# Snowflake on update

Tags: syntax, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

MySQL has an "on update" feature e.g.

```
    CREATE TABLE t1 (
     ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
```

I need a similar behavior in snowflake where I can update a column say "lastupdated" every time there is an update on the row.

Is this possible in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout "Snowflake Stream" option. You can create a stream on top of your table, and stream will have a couple of columns which will give you exactly what you're looking for!

Its not very well explored feature unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

In other database implementations this is achieved through triggers.
Snowflake doesn't support triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could create a stored procedure in Snowflake to accomplish what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to update a row with a timestamp 
or you could just update the field in your copy or replace statement. 
Similarly done this way: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00006uSiEKSA0/syntax-for-adding-a-column-with-currenttimestamp-default-constraint

Example 1:

```
> UPDATE <target_table>
       SET Lastupdate = current_timestamp()
        [ FROM <additional_tables> ]
        [ WHERE <condition> ]
```

Example 2:

```
>create or replace table x(i int, t timestamp default current_timestamp());

>insert into x(i) values(1);
```

borrowed from [this link](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00006uSiEKSA0/syntax-for-adding-a-column-with-currenttimestamp-default-constraint)

Answer (score 0):

as noted above, triggers are not supported - you'll have to do this explicitly in sql.  note that your process should also be handling data in some type of batches; if you are trying to do anything a single record at a time in snowflake - at least for any real volume - you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty nice feature request.  I've been using MS SQL Server for years... any "updated" columns were either done in the code or, as already indicated, using triggers.

I checked the snowflake docs and found this reference, which only applies to INSERTs and CTAS:

DEFAULT ... or AUTOINCREMENT ...

```
Specifies whether a default value is automatically inserted in the column if a value is not explicitly specified via an **INSERT or CREATE TABLE AS SELECT** statement:
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE t1 (
 ts TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9) as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 dt DATE as CURRENT_DATE,
 NAME VARCHAR(200)
);

insert into t1 (NAME) VALUES ('Jerry Smith');
insert into t1 (NAME) VALUES ('Gazorpazorp Smith');

select * from t1;
```

just means that your values change every time you select from the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of streams, external or internal stages and eventing , to record the DML CRUD changes. actually this combination is very elegant because your simulated triggers can trigger external events.

1) Create a stream

```
create stream supplierStream on table SupplierTable before(statement => 'yourGUID `statementID');`
```

2) Configure your event grid topic if using Azure.  let's say your topic name is "SupplierTopic"
[MS event grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/)

3)  create your notification integration

```
 CREATE NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION supplierIntegration
  ENABLED = true
  TYPE = QUEUE
  NOTIFICATION_PROVIDER = AZURE_STORAGE_QUEUE
```

4) create your stage

```
create or replace stage supplierStage 
  url='azure://your account container ID'
  storage_integration = SupplierIntegration;
```

5) consume the event grid event , in server or serverless system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `MERGE` combined with `UPDATE`?
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html